# VLC is not working with AMD gpu in 18.04

Tags: vlc, amd-graphics, 18.04, gpu-driver

Recently I have updated my Ubuntu distribution to 18.04 LTS. Since then I can't play videos in VLC using the AMD graphics card. Though it was fine in 17.04. When I am running the command

`DRI_PRIME=1 vlc Waking.Life.2001.1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG.mp4`

the output I am getting is this-

[output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGP4c.jpg)

But if I don't use `DRI_PRIME=1`, i.e. using the Intel graphics card the output is normal. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is related to hardware video acceleration.
The issue is caused by (at least) one of these alternatives:

1. VLC is misconfigured.
2. Hardware acceleration is not set up properly for your AMD graphics card.

### Quick Fix

Turn off hardware acceleration:

- Go to `VLC > Tools > Preferences > Input & Codecs Settings`.
- Set `Hardware-accelerated decoding` to `Disable`.

This is just a cure of the symptoms, helps to see any video at all. Remember to enable the setting again, when fixing the real cause of the problem.

### Check Setup

Install the packages `vdpauinfo` and `vainfo`.
These two are of great help when debugging hardware acceleration related issues.

Now open a terminal and run

```
vdpauinfo
```

as well as

```
vainfo
```

This gives a lot of insight to your current setup.

### Fix

I can't get into details here, there's way too many possibilities.
Take the output from the previous section as an indication which route to take.

Most likely, you need to install drivers. Drivers related to **VDPAU** and/or **VA-API**.

Here's a valuable page to get some more info: [VLX GPU Decoding](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_GPU_Decoding)

Comment: Deactivating hardware acceleration did it for me. Dunno if that addresses enough, but maybe my computer is just a little too old. Since I installed the AMD driver, many of my media tools, mic, webcam, etc all work better, but everything is just a bit slower. Could a full-swing graphics card just be too much for an older Win7 PC?